# Is it possible to tile the $3D$ space using octahedrons?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, normed-spaces, 3d, tiling

Cubes trivially tile the $3D$ space, but I wonder if this is also true for their duals: octahedrons?

[image]

For $2D$ case, the answer is yes: The dual of square can tile the floor, but for $d \geq 3$ it is not super obvious. Notice that for higher dimensions, you can consider the dual to be the unit ball with $L1$-norm.

Comment: Food for thought: does the octahedron have solid angles that can be summed up to $4\pi$?

Comment: Or dihedral angles that can be summed to $2\pi $?  Among Platonic solids only the cube will work, for the reasons suggested in these comments.

Comment: See [Tetrahedral-octahedral honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb) and [OcTet](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y43/PM2Ring/OcTetA3.jpg)

Comment: And here's an [animated version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e4GH8.gif), which makes it a little easier to see the 3D structure.

Comment: I agree that you need tetrahedrons to fill in the holes. In these parts the resulting repetitive structure is used in Christmas decoration items known as *Himmeli*. There is no English wikipedia article about them, but there is [a German one](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmeli). I made a few of those (out of straw and yarn) 20 years ago. IIRC the 12 edges sharing a common end point form a root system of type $A_3$.

Comment: [More elaborate designs](https://www.google.fi/search?q=himmeli&biw=1408&bih=720&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiv2uG_vN3PAhXCC5oKHaMHBTcQsAQIJg). Some of them show the repeating structure better than the pic in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we *can* do is stack an appropriate mixture of regular octahedra and regular tetrahedra.  Start with a regular octahedron.  Add two regular tetrahedra whose edges are congruent to those of the octahedron, matching one face of each tetrahedron to one of two opposite faces of the octahedron.  Now you have a solid whose dihedral angles come in supplementary pairs thus enabling a periodic stacking.

Comment: What can we say for N-Dim space? specially 4Dim

Comment: A mixture between the 4-d cross polytope (16-cell) and simplex (5-cell) won't work the same way as the 3-d analogue.  By using normal vectors to the cells we can calculate the relevant dihedral angles, and for the 4-d (or higher-dimensional) case they are not supplementary.

Comment: In 4D you don't need the simplex. 16-cell **alone** tiles the space pretty well.

Comment: Still different drom3-d, thanks @ivan.